# CheckBox display In HTML with vue configuration

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    checkeditems: []
  }
})
```

```html
<div v-for="item in instituteModel" v-if="instituteModel.length > 0">
  <input type="checkbox" id="item.id"     value="item.inst_name" v-model="checkeditems"/>
</div>
```

It dosent work i want to dislpay check box till item present in instituteModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have to bind `id` and `value`.This should work as suposed:

```
<div v-for="item in instituteModel" v-if="instituteModel.length > 0">
  <input type="checkbox" :id="item.id" :value="item.inst_name" v-model="checkeditems"/>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/wawucopoya/edit?html,js,output